# How do I make objects (textfields etc.) in the GUI disappear?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I want to make objects (like textfields and buttons) disappear and exchange them with different ones depending on what box you tick on the programs GUI.
How do I make them appear or disappear without deleting them? Or do I have to make different jFrames for each (and how)?
(I am programming with NetBeans IDE if that helps)

Answer (score 0):

In the source of the jFrame, or where ever you want to hide your GUI elements, if the main class is (should be) extending from the jFrame class, you can use

> remove

For example:

```
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();

    this.remove(btCalculateNumber);
    //button created with netbeans GUI
}
```

But I recommend reading [How to use setVisible in JFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176299/how-to-use-setvisible-in-jframes)

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many methods from throwing them off screen in the same method you things in html, but typically the best way to do it is with the 
'frame'.setVisible(false); method. You can tie this for example to radio list, and have a case structure for what's visible. (so basically button 1, frame 1,2,3, visable: 4 not, or button 2, frame 1,2,3, not visable, 4 visable... ext) For different jframes Class => extends jframe {code}

Honestly there's alot of good tutorials out their for this already, and I'd reccomend looking a couple up. (and also, avoid the netbeans drag/drop GUI builder till you understand... if your using it currently).

Comment: "Honestly there's alot of good tutorials out their for this already" would you mind linking a few?